# Calculus 3 integration problems

Tags: calculus, integration

Just wondering if anyone could help me sort out this old exam question:

$\ \vec F (x,y,z) = xe^{x^2+y^2} + ye^{x^2+y^2}+e^2 $

(A) Let C denote the path 
$\ (1 + cost, 2 + sin t, 3), 0 ≤ t ≤ 4π. $
Evaluate
$$\ \int_C \vec F . \vec {dr} $$
Justify your answer

(B) Find a function $\ ϕ : R^
3 → R $ such that $\ \vec F = ∇ϕ. $

(C) Evaluate

$$\ \int_Γ \vec F . \vec {dr} $$
Justify your answer

where Γ is the path
$\ (1 + cost, 2 + sin t, 3), 0 ≤ t ≤ π^2 $

---

I tried parameterization and ended up with this nasty yoke:

$$\ \int_0^{4 \pi} ((1+cos(t)) e^{(1+cos(t))^2+(2+sin(t))^2}) \vec i +(2+sin(t)) e^{(1+cos(t))^2+(2+sin(t))^2}) \vec j +e^3 \vec k )(-sin(t) \vec i +cos(t) \vec j + 0 \vec k $$

Which couldn't possible?

Part B I know how to do but have a feeling that part C depends on it

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to compute the integrale.
But let's go step by step :
$$f(t) = (1+\cos t)^2+(2+\sin t)^2 = 6 + 2\cos t+4\sin t$$

then apply the dot product :
$$((1+\cos t)e^{f(t)}\vec i+(2+\sin t)e^{f(t)}\vec j+e^3\vec k)(-\sin t \vec i +\cos t \vec j) = (-\sin t + 2\cos t)e^{f(t)}$$

Then we observe that :
$$f'(t) = -2\sin t+4\cos t $$

Can you finish it ?

Hint to check your results : as you will demonstrate it in B, $\vec F = \vec \nabla \phi $ and since C is a closed path, the result should be $0$

EDIT : how to end the question :

So at this point you have $$\int_0^{4\pi} \frac{1}{2}f'(t) e^{f(t)}dt = \frac{1}{2}\left [ e^{f(t)} \right ]_0^{4\pi} = \frac{1}{2}(e^8-e^8)= 0$$

Comment: thank you for your reply! but I'm afraid I'm a bit lost, I'm only new to calculus 3. Would you mind explaining it further?

Comment: @Lola I edited my answer, I hope that helps. A general advice : when you have $e^{f(t)}$ or $\cos(f(t))$ or $\sin(f(t))$ always look for $f'(t)$